# Primordial Particle System - 2D Particle Interaction in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, particles

**This is only my resurrection attempt. Read more below.**

I am posting this only as an effort to preserve an interesting question posted by a new member here last week, which he later voluntarily removed by himself; even after question received several up-votes and stars in the matter of hours after posting it.

Link to the original / now deleted question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478107/2d-particle-interactions

I am not an expert in this field, a little interested at the moment, however, I was smart enough to save all the code and links offline for later ;)

**The original question - Reconstruction**

---

**The problem**

I want to simulate and visualize particle interactions that are governed by: [ [image source](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep37969/figures/1) ]

[image: PPS Pseudo Code]

With the given settings:

> PPS = 〈r = 5, α = 180°, β = 17°, v = 0.67〉

Effectively replicating the following observations: [ [image source](https://www.nature.com/articles/srep37969/figures/3) ]

[image: PPS Generations]

As shown in the following video:

> [How life emerges from a simple particle motion law](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=makaJpLvbow)

But the creators didn't provide their source code as they stated:

> "CAN YOU PUBLISH THE CODE PLEASE?"
>
> "We put everything needed into the Scientific Reports paper, which is
>   open-access. There is not more to it. We once compressed the code of
>   the fully running model into a tweet. This was in those days when
>   tweets had 140 characters. The model is super-simple and super-short."

Referring to the pseudo-code included at the beginning of this question.

**QUESTION**

*important note: original author's code work is not copied here*

How can I make this work as it is shown?

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are already several solutions / working code examples in JavaScript for PPS system:

1. by user **nagualdesign** @ github

https://github.com/nagualdesign/Primordial-Particle-System

older / original versions @ Google Drive:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eX_cczNM4qfDue6j83f8T4gG4ecjSV-p
>
> https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KoJf753p3HXPHwP4N2lW9cWLXgusTP72

I will only post here as a snippet his older simpler code version.
Please visit his GitHub page for the most current version.

```js
// author: user "nagualdesign" @ github
// github repository: https://github.com/nagualdesign/Primordial-Particle-System
// For more information visit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=makaJpLvbow
// This video focuses primarily on specific values of alpha, beta, v and r
// It goes on to show the effects of altering the values of alpha and beta
// To replicate the video it is necessary to tune the density of particles
// Density depends on the screen size, as well as particle size and number
// You can also increase/decrease density by zooming in/out and refreshing

// Global variables:
var a=180; // Alpha in degrees
var b=17; // Beta in degrees
var v=0.67; // Speed of particles
var r=5.0; // Radius of neighbourhood

// Convert to radians!
a=(a/180)*Math.PI;
b=(b/180)*Math.PI;

var canvas, context; // HTML canvas
var t=40; // Time interval in milliseconds
var s=5; // Size/scale of particles
var n=1200; // Number of particles
var p=new Array(n); // Particles

function init() {
 // Set up canvas:
 canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
 canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
 canvas.height=window.innerHeight;
 context=canvas.getContext("2d");
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) { // Randomize position and orientation of particles:
  p[i]=new Array(4); // Each particle has 4 variables
  p[i][0]=Math.random()*window.innerWidth; // Set random x coordinate
  p[i][1]=Math.random()*window.innerHeight; // Set random y coordinate
  p[i][2]=Math.random()*2*Math.PI; // Set random orientation
 }
}

function draw() {
 context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height); // Clear canvas
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) { // For each particle:
  // Set fill colour based on number of neighbours:
  let fc='#00C200'; // Green
  if (p[i][3]>35) fc='#F8E302'; // Yellow
  else if (p[i][3]>16) fc='#0064FF'; // Blue
  else if (p[i][3]>15) fc='#FF0792'; // Magenta
  else if (p[i][3]>12) fc='#A4714B'; // Brown
  // Draw particle:
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(p[i][0],p[i][1],s,0,2*Math.PI);
  context.fillStyle=fc;
  context.fill();
 }
}

function scope(ang) { // Ensure angles are between 0 and 2*pi radians!
 while (ang>(2*Math.PI)) ang=ang-(2*Math.PI);
 while (ang<0) ang=ang+(2*Math.PI);
 return ang;
}

function loop() {
 for (i=0; i<n; i++) { // For each particle:
 // Count neighbors within radius r:
 let nLeft=0, nRight=0, nTotal=0;
 for (j=0; j<n; j++) if (i!=j) { // Compare every other particle:
 let sX=p[j][0]-p[i][0]; // X axis separation
 let sY=p[j][1]-p[i][1]; // Y axis separation
 let sD=Math.sqrt((sX*sX)+(sY*sY)); // Separation distance
 if (sD<(r*s*2)) { // Distance is within radius r
 nTotal++; // Increase count
 let sA=scope(Math.atan2(sY,sX)); // Separation angle
 if (scope(sA-p[i][2])<Math.PI) nRight++; // Neighbour on right
 else nLeft++; // Neighbour on left
 }
 }
 p[i][3]=nTotal; // Used for colouring particles

 // delta_phi = alpha + beta × N × sign(R - L)
 let deltaPhi=a+(b*nTotal*Math.sign(nRight-nLeft));

 // turn right delta_phi
 p[i][2]+=deltaPhi;
 p[i][2]=scope(p[i][2]); // Keep angles within scope!

 // Move forward v
 p[i][0]+=(v*s*2*Math.cos(p[i][2])); // X coordinate
 p[i][1]+=(v*s*2*Math.sin(p[i][2])); // Y coordinate

 // Wrap screen edges, Pac-Man style!
 if (p[i][0]<(s*-1)) p[i][0]=(canvas.width+s);
 else if (p[i][0]>(canvas.width+s)) p[i][0]=(s*-1);
 if (p[i][1]<(s*-1)) p[i][1]=(canvas.height+s);
 else if (p[i][1]>(canvas.height+s)) p[i][1]=(s*-1);
 }
 draw(); // Update canvas
}

function run() {
 init();
 run=setInterval(loop,t);
}
```

```html
<body style="margin:0; background:#000; overflow:hidden;" onLoad="run();">
<canvas id="canvas" onclick="window.clearTimeout(run)"></canvas>
</body>
```

2. by user **elggem** @ github

> https://github.com/elggem/js-primordialparticles [demo](https://elggem.github.io/js-primordialparticles/)

---